# Swift Functions Stuck

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm new to Swift and programing in general, but my function before I updated to the latest xCode was

```
func setPressedAction(action: () -> ()) {
    self.pressedAction = action
}
```

With the update I am getting

`Method 'setPressedAction' with Objective-C selector 'setPressedAction:' conflicts with setter for 'pressedAction' with the same Objective-C selector`

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `pressedAction` property. You can't declare an instance method named `setPressedAction` under that situation, because in Objective-C's mind, that's the setter for the property. Just give the function a different name.

The reason this didn't emerge until the update is that Apple fixed a bug (closed a loophole) so that you couldn't make this mistake accidentally - as you were doing.